# at which $x \in R^n$ is f totally differentiable and calculate its total derivative

Tags: analysis

Let $A \in M_{m,n}(R)$, $b\in R^m$ , and define $f : R^n \rightarrow R^m $ by $f(x) = Ax + b$; $x \in R^n$.
Investigate at which $x \in R^n$ is *f* totally differentiable and calculate its total derivative.

Could someone help me with this question? We need to show that since f is differentiable and since we are in Euclidean space I was thinking that probably we could use the fact that all 1st order partial derivatives of f exist.

Comment: You are looking at a (an afffine) linear map. You need to show that up to first order it can be approximated by a linear map. Just plug in the definitions. (the derivative is given by  $x\mapsto Ax$...)

Answer (score 1):

From
$$\begin{array}{l}
f(x + tv) - f(x) = A(x + tv) - Ax\\
 = Ax + t \cdot Av + b - Ax - b\\
 = t \cdot Av
\end{array}$$
follows
$$\frac{{f(x + tv) - f(x)}}{t} = Av$$
and therefore
$$Df(x)(v) = Av$$
for all $x \in {\mathbb{R}^n}$ and $v \in {\mathbb{R}^n}$.
The derivative is calculated directly by the partials.
$$\frac{{\partial {f^j}}}{{\partial {x^i}}}(x) = a_i^j,1 \leqslant i \leqslant n,1 \leqslant j \leqslant m$$

Comment: This is the total derivative. I replaced $h$ by $tv$. Please look:
$$\begin{gathered}
  f:{\mathbb{R}^n} \to {\mathbb{R}^m} \hfill \\
  Df:{\mathbb{R}^n} \to Hom({\mathbb{R}^n},{\mathbb{R}^m}) \hfill \\
  Df(x) \in Hom({\mathbb{R}^n},{\mathbb{R}^m}) \hfill \\
  Df(x):{\mathbb{R}^n} \to {\mathbb{R}^m} \hfill \\
  Df(x)(v) = Av \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$